# Sharing data between controllers with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there another way other than creating a factory or service todo this?

Comment: After asking this I realized how much I shouldn't do this. **Use a factory**!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904174/two-views-in-one-angularui-router-state-sharing-scope/21924873#21924873

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to share data between state controllers:

1. Put the data on a common ancestor's `$scope`, so all the controllers in question see the data on their local scopes.
2. Use a global service (as you said).
3. Create a "local service" (using the `resolve` config) in a common ancestor's state.
4. Pass the data as `$stateParams` (useful only in some very specific situations).

The first one is usually the best bet, as putting the data on `$scope` also allows you to easily `$watch` the changes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm realizing that I **have to** create a service

Answer (score 0):

Well this may not be the best but it works for me pretty well in an app i develop, and the trick was using the local storage, for example in my search view:

```
controller: 'SearchCtrl'
state: 'search'
```

i get a list of results from a web service and stored them like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('results', angular.toJson(results)); // assuming a json response
```

then i made a common transition to another state `$state.transitionTo('results')`:

```
controller: 'ResultCtrl'
state: 'results'
```

and finally get the results from the `localStarage` in a scope variable of `ResultCtrl`:

```
$scope.results = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('results'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your routes like this:

```
.state('parent', {
  url: "/parent",
  abstract: true,
  controller: 'ParentCtrl'
})

.state('app.foo', {
  url: "/foo",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/foo.html",
      controller: 'FooCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

And access from `FooCtrl` the functions and data that are in `ParentCtrl`

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you post a http://plnkr.co, please?