# Angular: Sharing login status across controllers

Tags: angularjs, authentication, mean

I have a fairly simple angular app (working off the MEAN stack) that is not using the ui-router (and I would like to keep it that way for right now).

I am wondering what the best way to share a users "logged in" status across the app is.

For instance, I would like a directive to show "Signup or Login" if the user is not logged in, or "Hello, username" if the user is logged in.

Throughout my app, many directives refer to the logged in status and so it seems that using multiple Controllers and declaring a logged in `$scope` property on each one is not the best idea. How could I achieve this?

As a follow up, any recommendations on the best way to know if a user is logged in or not? Right now I am basing it off an `auth-token` that is stored in local storage, but it could be cookies as well.

I would like to know a/the best practice way that I could store more than a user's logged in status but also their information (name, items picked out etc.) and keep it synced to my server (so if they log in on another computer, their cart would persist).

Thanks

Comment: Share the logged in boolean across the controllers with a factory. Simple example of factory data shared between controllers http://stackoverflow.com/a/21924873/1803298

Answer (score 0):

Write a service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('Auth', function() {
    var loggedInState = {}; // log in state data

    var logIn = function() {
        // send log in request
    }

    return {
        state: loggedInState,
        logIn: logIn
    }
})
```

Now you inject this service everywhere you want to know if they were logged in, and check the state

Comment: Okay, so then if I wanted to conditionally show or hide something in a directive, that has this injected, how do I do so.  In other words, how do I access this `Auth` service's properties and set them as `$scope` in a directive once it is injected?

Comment: Inject the service in the controller, and assign the property you need from the service to the controllers scope, or the whole service if you prefer.

Comment: Got it. I see, inject the controller into the `controller` property of the directive.

Comment: You inject the service into the controller, directive, whatever: .directive('header', function(Auth, newFactory) { ... }

Comment: When I try this, returning an object for `loggedInState`, nothing appears in my template.  However, if I enter an object directly in the return value, the values from that object do appear.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: To clarify, I asked a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358107/why-can-i-access-data-directly-returned-by-factory-but-not-through-a-declared-o