# Why can I access data directly returned by factory, but not through a declared object?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a User Factory in angular. For some reason, I can access values returned by the Factory in certain situations, but not in others: Like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('UserFactory', function () {

    return {
      returnedPerson: returnedPerson,
      thing: thing,
      //This works
      person: {
        name: 'Test',
        age: 5
      },
    };

    //This doesn't work
    returnedPerson = {
      name: 'returnme',
      loggedIn: true
    }

    //Neither does this
    function thing () {
      return {
        name: 'test',
      }
    }
```

I don't see what the difference is, and would like to be able to access the value as an object because I would like this `UserFactory` to maintain a user's data across my app.

In other words, I am planning to inject it into several different controllers, and would like to be able to set $scope.loggedIn in any controller and have that update across every place that the `UserFactory` is used. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are certainly able to do that in a factory.  However, you'll simply have to move your object and function declaration before your return statement. Anything after the return is unreachable:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('UserFactory', function () {
 var returnedPerson,
   thing;

//works now
returnedPerson = {
  name: 'returnme',
  loggedIn: true
};

//also works
thing = function () {
  return {
    name: 'test',
  }
};

return {
  returnedPerson: returnedPerson,
  thing: thing,
  //This works
  person: {
    name: 'Test',
    age: 5
  },
};
```

Factories are also singletons, so you will only have one instance of whatever is returned here.  That is convenient when injecting it into multiple controllers.