# Routing and pushing to array AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a list of contacts, where I have two views.
One view that lists all the contacts and gives the option to add a new contact, being a button, not an actual space where I put the information.
The other views is when I click on the plus sign, that would give me the field to put a new information.
What I am trying to do is using angular, after I put all the information in the field, have updated on the array. My idea is that since I am not refreshing the page, the array should contain the new added contact, but it's not happening.
Do you guys know why?
I could put the code here, but honestly I just want to know if what I am trying to do is hypothetically possible

---

Edit: Everything was fixed using a factory ;). Thank you guys.

Comment: give us some code, please.

Comment: Put the scenario into your head and see if it's possible.

Comment: If you tell me that is possible, with angular, have two views, and after adding the contact on the second view, have the first view being update with the list + the new contact, then I will put the code.. otherwise is pointless i believe. Sry

Comment: Yes, possible, see answer/demo with two views here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21924873/1803298

Comment: If my factory demo helped don't be shy with the up vote on the answer :)

Comment: I am really sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly I think what you need is a service to hold the contacts, that way if you update the service your scope property for the contacts updates as well