# How do I perform a transition within a state?

Tags: angular-ui-router

```
$stateProvider.state("browse", {
  url : "/browse/{id}",
  controller : "BrowseCtrl",
  templateUrl : "browse.html"
});
```

I will be frequently transitioning from /browse/1 to /browse/2  (and /browse/3 and /browse/400).

ui-router's natural behavior is to reload the template and reload the
controller.    That is not what I want.

What I want is for the controller (or somebody) to be notified "you
used to be at /browse/1; now you are at /browse/2.  Handle it."  My code
will update the screen as necessary (by doing a clever animation from
1 to 2).

If, however, the transition is from some other state, then I would
like it to do the ordinary thing: load the template and the
controller.

All my searches have turned up is fancy ways to animate
transitions out of one state and into another, which is not what I want
to do.

Nor (so far as I can tell) is this "sticky".  A sticky state would
maintain its scope from one invocation to another -- I want to keep
the scope only as long as the transitions are within this state.

I am sure there is a keyword or an option or something for this, I
just cannot find it.

**EDIT:** It occurs to me that I could accomplish all this if I could just mark {id} as not being important; that {id} changing does not constitute a transition and the only reaction to the change is that $stateParams is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think best is to have different states, in your case browser.one, browser.two, browser.three and so on.

Check this detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904174/two-views-in-one-angularui-router-state-sharing-scope) for sharing data between states.

Comment: So your idea is that I have 2^32 different states, one for each integer?

Comment: lol I guess what you'll need then is to add [states programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866387/angular-ui-router-programmatically-add-states)